# Render deployed REST API working fine in Insomnia, but not on localhost deployed website

Tags: rest, deployment, web-applications, render, mern

I have created a blog app using MERN stack. I have deployed the REST API using render, and I am testing the API using insomnia. It works fine in insomnia when I am creating a new post and sign up.
[insomnia testing REST API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyS6R.png)
[insomnia signup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pllfA.png)

But when I am doing this same on local host using the render REST API deployed link, its not working.
This is the error that I am getting while creating a new post
[Creating Post Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDaRH.png)
This is the error that I am getting while sign up
[Creating New User Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrVE1.png)

This is the create blog function:
[create blog function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFknL.png)

This is the signup function
[sign up code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUdh6.png)

This is the index.js code in my server folder
[index.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6sk3.png)